# Datatables table is not loading from JSON (rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, datatables

I have a rails app that is supposed to parse a JSON file and display the data in a filterable table.

I am using datatables.net.

However, the table just gets stuck saying "loading" and never finishes.

Here is the url: http://www.additiveanalytics.com/solutions/maternity

Gemfile:

```
# Use datatables to dynamically filter data
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
# jquery-datatables-rails depends on sass-rails
gem 'sass-rails'
```

File app/assets/javascripts/maternity.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#maternity').dataTable
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    "sAjaxSource": "/data/maternity.json"
```

JSON:
http://www.additiveanalytics.com/data/maternity.json

File app/views/solutions/maternity.html.erb:

```
<table id="maternity" class="display" data-source="data/maternity.json">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Hospital</th>
            <th>% Newborns Delivered Early</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
       </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed it.

My JSON was an array of objects. Instead, DataTables was expecting an array of arrays.

So I changed the JSON to be an array of arrays, not an array of objects. Now it is working.

I would guess there is a way to make it work with an array of objects (which is nicer, because it's easier for a human to read) but I do not know what that is.